# Is a bad practice to Return different types when overloading a method?

Tags: .net, overloading

Given this example:

```
Interface CustomersDao
    Function Get(ByVal Id As Integer) As Customer
    Function Get(ByVal Filter As Filter) As IList(Of Customer)
End Interface

Public Sub Main()
    Dim Customer As Customer = CustomersDao.Get(4)

    Dim Filter As New CustomersDao.Filter
    Filter.Category = 2
    Dim Customers As IList(Of Customer) = CustomersDao.Get(Filter)
End Sub
```

Is it a bad practice to return diferent types in the same method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend calling the second one `GetAll`.

Right now, it isn't obvious that the second method returns a collection.
You should strive to ensure that your classes are as obvious as possible and do not contain any unexpected surprises.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I think the question is poorly formed **but** overloaded methods returning different types is not inherently bad practice.

Comment: 1+. I believe it is bad practice.

Comment: GetAll or GetCustomers, as if a Filter is provided, presumably it won't return "All"...

Answer (score 4):

No, I would say that is perfectly fine.

Comment: +1 I agree **unless** the overload is altering basic purpose. For example, a `PaintBlack()` method which returns different types is just polymorphism but it **should not** paint a horse solid black and paint a zebra in stripes.

Comment: -1. Find an example in .NET Framework. I cannot think of one.

Comment: @Aliostad: I am not sure about instance methods, but there are static methods in CLR with variable return types ([Activator.CreateInstance(string,string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) vs [Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he47tyc4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), for example). But I also consider this ugly, especially since one of the overloads return an `Object` (and compiler won't mind if you assign it an `ObjectHandle`).

Comment: @Groo Jon Skeet did remind me a few. But they comprise an exception and only cases where it makes sense.

Comment: @Aliostad: agreed, I don't see the point in doing this at all. I do expect these "similar" methods to have similar but different names (like `Find` and `FindAll`, for example), which makes the distinction more obvious (and intellisense shows them one after another, so they are easy to spot also).

Answer (score 3):

In your example the API makes sense and looks intuitive. Especially since you named the function arguments Id and Filter which, IMO, imply a single value result and a collection respectively. The drawback being that in an intellisense scenario you would have to examine each overload to see what it does rather just seeing the proper method to call in the suggested list. E.g. `GetSingle(int id)` vs. `GetAll()` vs. `GetSubset(string filter)`

I could imagine scenarios where overloading and returning different types could quickly become very confusing. Especially if you start introducing hacks to work around an established usage of the API.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe it is a **bad practice.**

**Try finding an overload in .NET Framework** that returns a different type, *I cannot think of one*.

---

## UPDATE

There are some methods in the .NET Framework as such [DateTime.Subtract()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.Subtract) but they are the exception and not the rule and only cases where **the intention is completely obvious**.

Comment: There are a number of methods which return an interface

Comment: TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383497.aspx Some methods return DateTime, some DateTimeOffset.

Comment: @Jon Agreed. Also in `DateTime` we have `Subtract` and `Add` but they comprise less than 1% of cases and in these cases, I can accept an exception.

Comment: @Aliostad: I generally agree that it's a bad idea. Just wanted to give an example from the framework :)

Comment: Thanks @Jon. It was my lucky day today, had the pleasure/honour of a brief conversation with you.

Comment: Do they give a badge for that?

Comment: They must do. It can be a feature request :)

Comment: Sorry to bump the dead but I noticed today that various methods in the `Math` namespace do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this is not best practice as it doesnt make for intuitive, readable code if variable declarations are not immediately visible. I would generally use GetById and GetForFilter, GetAll, etc which describes better the action which is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Returning interfaces is appropriate since (sound-practices-permitting) an interface is going to link different classes to a similar problem domain and guarantee a consistent set of methods.

Different types, however, deserve a smell-check because it's easier to remember the different args you can use to get at data than it is to remember the various types returned or having to branch your own code to accommodate those types even when you do remember.

The missing alternative that no one's provided here is to overload both as returning a list even if it seems silly for id to only return a one-item list. It's worked great for jQuery which is the JavaScript equivalent of a massively overloaded function.

Consistent returns means I only have to remember what your API does for me rather than what I have to do for it.